# "Too many arguments" on SECOND button click, C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have a sproc that executes a search on button click. The search page is simply a combo box and a text box. The user selects the column from the combo box they want to search on and enter the value in the textbox. The sproc executes fine on the first attempt regardless of which value is chosen from the combo box. Any subsequent clicks on the search button gives me the "too many arguments" error.

**C#**

```
public partial class InitialDebt : Form
{
    static string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnStr"].ConnectionString;
    static SqlConnection misc = new SqlConnection(conn);
    static SqlCommand initDebt = misc.CreateCommand();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(initDebt);
    static int index = 0;

public InitialDebt()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (ddlFilter.Text == "SELECT")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a value from the drop down list");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
    string Filter = ddlFilter.Text;
    string SearchStr = txtSearchStr.Text;
    initDebt.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    initDebt.CommandText = "mySPROC";
    initDebt.Parameters.Add("@Filter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Filter;
    initDebt.Parameters.Add("@SearchStr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SearchStr;
    da.Fill(dt);
            misc.Open();
            txtSS.Text = dt.Rows[0]["SS_Num"].ToString();
            txtLName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["last_Name"].ToString();
            txtFName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["first_name"].ToString();
            txtAgt.Text = dt.Rows[0]["agent_num"].ToString();
            txtStore.Text = dt.Rows[0]["agent_name"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no records that match your search criteria. " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        misc.Close();
    }
}
```

}

I have tried:

- changing my parameters to initDebt.Parameters.Add("@Filter",
  SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Filter ??"";
- Adding initDebt.Parameters.Clear(). When I do this the sproc does not
  execute.
- I also tried it with and without the length of the parameter.
- Verified the parameter names are the same

**SQL**

```
@Filter varchar(20),
@SearchStr varchar(40)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT SS_Num, upper(Last_Name) as Last_name, upper(First_Name) as first_name, 
        upper(Address) as address, upper(City) as city, upper(State) as state, 
        Zip_code, upper(Agency_code) as agency_code, Agent_num, 
        upper(Agent_name) as agent_name, debt_date, debt_amount
FROM myTable
WHERE 
(
CASE
    WHEN @Filter = 'SS #' THEN SS_Num
    WHEN @Filter = 'LAST NAME' THEN Last_Name
    WHEN @Filter = 'CITY' THEN City
    WHEN @Filter = 'AGENT #' THEN Agent_num
    WHEN @Filter = 'STORE' THEN Agent_Name
END
    like '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
)
END
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Don't hang on to your command and connection on the form level.  Just create them as needed in your methods, and enclose them in `using` blocks to ensure they're properly disposed.  Let the connection pool do its thing.

Comment: `initDebt` is a global variable.  Every time you click the button you're adding *more* parameters to it

Comment: Static connection. That's worst practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your command and connections inside the method and dispose them when done. Using 'using' blocks will do fine.

Also this will solve your 'parameters' problem as you would be creating a new command and connection object for every new click.